# Else statement output not responding when testing code

Tags: c++, if-statement

i wanted to use an else statement, but for some reason it doesn't work.
I've tried a lot of different things to solve this problem but i just can't find a solution. here's the whole code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    HANDLE a = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 3);

    cout << "what's your name? " <<endl;

    string name;
    cin >> name;
    string namesuggestion;

    namesuggestion = name.substr(0, 12);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 5);
    cout << "the length of this name is: " << name.length();

    int txtlength = name.length();

    if (txtlength > 12){ 
        cout << "\nNah, bro.\n";
        cout << txtlength;
        cout << " characters in a single name is a Little too much.\nTry something shorter.";
        cout << "\nMaybe, \"" + namesuggestion + "\"?";
    }
    else {
        cout << "So you want to be called " + name + "?";
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

and here's the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
}
    else {
        cout << "So you want to be called " + name + "?";
    }
```

The output would be a text saying "what's your name, then telling how many letters this name consists of. If the name consists of more than 12 letters, the program will tell the user to make up a new name, along with a suggestion for a new name.

But if the name is less than 12 letters, it would say: "So you want to be called {name of the user}?

so the problem here is, is that the program won't respond to the user having a name of less than 12 letters.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

Edit: this is solved, the problem was that the debug console was messed up because of the code responsible for changing the color of text.

Comment: *" it doesn't work"*. What does that mean precisely?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's your input? What's the expected output? What's the actual output?

Comment: Works as expected [here](https://ideone.com/Z6F0qD) (after removing windows specific code).

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and see what the value of `txtlength` was?

Comment: @crashmstr the value of txtlength seems to be measured normally, because the program is clearly able to tell if it consists of more than 12 characters.

Comment: Cut the Windows-specific console manipulation. (Don't waste time on presentation before your program works.)

Comment: @molbdnilo thank you, after creating an entire new project -  which resetted the console - and deleting the code responsible for the windows specific console manipulation, the script finally works.

Comment: @Wafelranger Well, yes. But if you debug the code and see what the value is when you *think* it might be `<= 12`... that is what debugging is for: to examine the state of the code and see *exactly* why it goes into one branch or another.

Answer (score 0):

You seem not to understand how an if-else clause works:
You are doing:

```
if (txtlength > 12){ 
  ...
}
else if (txtlength <= 12){
    cout << "So you want to be called " + name + "?";
}
```

While you should be doing:

```
if (txtlength > 12){ 
  ...
}
else {
    cout << "So you want to be called " + name + "?";
}
```

(Within the `else` you don't need an extra `if`)

**Edit:**

Please use this line to show the length:

```
cout << "the length of this name is: " << name.length() << "\n";
```

Comment: although this is true, this two pieces of code do the same, so they won't solve whatever the problem is.

Comment: this was my first input, but that didn't work, so i changed it to else if to hope for the best. didn't work either.

Comment: `if`/`else` is not a "loop". Also, they don't need to do the `if` on the `else` *if* the `else if` condition is the negation of the original `if` (i.e. anything passing the `else if` is everything that does not pass the `if`).

Comment: @Wafelranger: are you sure? I have the impression that your code is working fine but your output is messed up due to the weirdly placed `\n` characters.

Comment: @dominique that may be true, i'll try to remove the \n parts. which parts do you mean exactly, every \n, or specific ones?

Comment: I edited my answer, can you modify your code accordingly? Because of the lack of newline at the end of that line, you can't be sure that the length is calculated correctly.

Comment: @dominique i've tried removing every \n, but this didn't work either.

Comment: You should *add* '\n' in the end of each sentence you want to output. As a side note, do not use `+` to concatenate and output strings if you can just output then, like that: `std::cout << "So you want to be called " << name << "?\n";`